# How to make GTK Inspector changes permanent?

Tags: gnome-text-editor, gtk4, gtkinspector

The "new" **Text Editor** in Ubuntu 22.10 / 23.04 / 23.10 (and I am not talking about the old `gedit` tool) has large top margin in the edit area (just above the first line) as shown below:

[image]

Today, I came across the **GTK Inspector** which can be activated from the **Text Editor** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (capital `i`). After navigating to **Objects** → **Properties** and changing the value of **top-margin** from 12 to 2, this top margin size is reduced to a more meaningful setting:

[image]

[image]

However, this setting change is not permanent; after I close and restart `gnome-text-editor` this size reverts to the old value (12).

Is there a method to make the change permanent? I guess, some modification in `~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css` is needed; however **GTK Inspector** does not help me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, That is a GTK Widget "property"

#### Option 1: If GUI is declarative as text

- It could be changed in runtime package only for these cases:

  1. App which uses GTK Builder and GUI is loaded from XML in runtime.
  2. App which based on Script (For example Python).

  Otherwise no other way then changing source code itself as app doesn't use GTK builder it is based on compiled programming language. GUI is embedded in binary format inside executable or its shared library.
- GTK Widget "property" are different than CSS Style. I did check its: `padding-top` and `margin-top` they are not the same and they just add more space. Even going down in hierarchy has no effect, I suspect it get a updated/overridden by runtime program.

  Anyway, here what I tried first to debug and trace, may be I missed something:

  ```
  .editor.GtkSourceView.monospace.sourceview.view {
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-top-color: rgb(0,255,0);
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-left-color: rgb(0,255,255);
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
  }

  .editor.GtkSourceView.monospace.sourceview.view > text {
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 5px;
    border-top-color: rgb(255,255,0);
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-left-color: rgb(0,255,255);

    /* not effective ??? */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,200);
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  ```

  [Screenshot of GTK inspector CSS tweak trial on gnome-text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdT6u.png)

  ##### Update: Try and error, well negative value works good ‼️

  > ```
  > .editor.GtkSourceView.monospace.sourceview.view {
  >   margin-top: -12px;
  > }
  > ```

  **Note:** If you wonder where the "`editor GtkSourceView monospace sourceview view`" CSS selector is coming from, check: GTK Inspector > Objects > Use Pick tool > CSS Nodes > Style Classes.

#### Option 2: Modify source code, need knowledge of build process

- If you choose to go with source code modification, I expect this what you looking for:

  https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-text-editor/-/blob/main/src/editor-page.ui#L30

  ```
  ...
  <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scroller">
    <property name="hexpand">true</property>
    <property name="vexpand">true</property>
    <child>
      <object class="EditorSourceView" id="view">
        <style>
          <class name="editor"/>
        </style>
        <signal name="notify::font-scale" handler="font_scale_changed_cb" swapped="true"/>
        <property name="auto-indent">true</property>
        <property name="top-margin">12</property>
  ...
  ```

#### Option 3: Just a hack, modify the text resources inside the binary

- Well, this is just a shortcut/hack. I wouldn't recommend it in "Free Software" world where source code is open and free.

  1. Install bless or any other hex editor.
  2. Make a copy of executable file

     ```
     ## Check for file path
     which gnome-text-editor

     /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor

     ## Confirm not just a proxy/wrapper script
     file /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor

     /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b2b5986d56418c22adb1e35431cb650c259bba7c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

     ## Copy and make a backup
     cp /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor ./Desktop/gnome-text-editor.mod
     cp /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor.backup
     ```
  3. Open `./Desktop/gnome-text-editor.mod` with `bless`. Search for "top-margin". You may find 4 match the one in "editor" object is our target. Mine in Ubuntu 23.10 is around offset 405506 (decimal). Change value "12" to wanted value but keep it two digits (Zero as "00")
  4. Test it then copy it back

     ```
     ./Desktop/gnome-text-editor.mod
     sudo cp ./Desktop/gnome-text-editor.mod ./Desktop/gnome-text-editor
     ```

  [Screenshot Modification in bless hex editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBYHB.jpg)

  [Screenshot of resulted gnome-text-editor with top-margin was set to 0px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH7x7.jpg)

  This  could be overwritten by any future update. Up to you if you want to prevent that by  locking its package update within APT or DPKG.

Comment: Still I am also unable to find out what this **top-margin** (=12) "thing" is.

Comment: So, I understand that the `<property name="top-margin">12</property>` ***can*** be changed at run-time, but **there is no way to make it permanent** so the each time `gnome-text-editor` is restarted it is set to the value I want. (Except for the binary hack last-resort you mention at the end of your answer!).

Comment: @FedKad it is an object (widget in this case) custom property not mapped directly to CSS value by its developer. Using GTK Inspector is the only way to change it on runtime for this case and GTK inspector does not support scripting.  Yes you left with 2 options:  quick one, change binary (hack), clean and regular way, change the source code and rebuild the package and reinstall it.

Comment: I tested the third option and it is working. I will live with the third option then. Thanks. I accepted your answer and I will wait for 24 hours more for the bounty. :)

Comment: : ) me too @FedKad I would choose the shortest way, only if it is worthy for long run or challenged to go far. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, certainly the least invasive way to change one app. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @FedKad try & error I found a CSS tweak that works, updated my answer.

Comment: Yes. `margin-top: -12px;` works!

Comment: You may need to ***highlight somehow the portion of your answer that you most recently updated***. This was the exact solution I was looking for.

Comment: @FedKad Yeah more better, updated.

Answer (score 1):

The GTK inspector will help, you'll need to select the "CSS Nodes" tab in order to find out what to change. That tab will show you which CSS node has been changed. The approach of changing your "local GTK4 CSS" is correct, changing it in your theme will otherwise last only until the next update.
Example with the gnome-calculator (I don't have gedit installed):

```
GTK_DEBUG=interactive gnome-calculator
```

Two windows will open, one is the calculator, the other one the "debugger". Lets check the red cancel button:
[image]

Press the "Select Object Button" and click on the Control you would like to check- the debugger will vanish and display the properties. Change to "CSS Nodes":
[image]

The "C" button is a "clear-button" or "text-button" style. In a first step you could try to change something using the css tab - which is a playground:

```
button.clear-button label {color:yellow;}
```

and make sure the css is toggled on:
[image]

So you've changed the color of the button - as an example. To persist it, you will have to write this line into a file: either into

- ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
- ~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css

depending on if GTK4.0 is already used by the app or GTK3.0

This is a tedious job, but this way I managed to create my own theme since the CSS is not really documented.

Comment: Sorry, but I need more detailed instructions: (1) In the "CSS Nodes" tab (selected from left) there is a highly nested tree and I don't know where to start. (2) Which local user file should I edit to make these "changes" permanent? Please, expand your answer by giving the exact steps needed to be carried out for solving my very specific problem stated in question.

Comment: The problem is that the **top-margin** (=12) "thing" is only present in the **Properties** tab and I haven't found it in any place under the **CSS Nodes** tab's tree. :(

Comment: Although this does not answer my question, it is a good tutorial about **GTK Inspector**. Upvoted. Thanks.

Comment: It is "margin-top" in the CSS field. You might consider to look up the parent widget (in hierarchy) . Debugging "mousepad" if have a texview (where the letters reside) and its parent "scrolledwindow". To get more space you can either use "padding" in the textview or "margin" in the scrolled window - your miles may vary....